# How to easily reposition taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

It's easy to drag and move the taskbar if there aren't many open windows taking up space on the taskbar.  You just have to find an empty spot on the taskbar, then click and drag.

But if the taskbar is full, then it's very difficult to do this.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Resize the taskbar to two (or more) rows by clicking and dragging the edge. Then there will be a lot of empty space to grab, e.g. under the Start button. After you move it into the new position, resize it to the desired size.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the start menu and hit Properties>Taskbar and choose it there, but I don't know if that'd count as easy. Sometimes you can also drag in between the start button and the first icon, but that's even harder. =/

Answer (score 0):

If your system tray has a space in it, you can use that. Otherwise, there's a considerable gap inbetween the last icon and the system tray.

Comment: The gap isn't very big if there are enough programs open.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a way as easy as that. My advise if you can't close even one application, try opening one. This will cause the task bar to create a second layer, there will be a little scroll bar between the last icon and the system tray. go furthest down or left depending on where the bar is. There should be plenty of room there.